# Unresolved reference in build.gradle

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have been trying to agree with Gradle terms of service. However, I have experienced the following issue:
`Unresolved reference: gradleEnterprise`

I have added such code to `build.gradle` file:

```
gradleEnterprise {
        buildScan {
            termsOfServiceUrl.set("https://gradle.com/terms-of-service")
            termsOfServiceAgree.set("yes")
        }
    }
```

With a help of GPT-3.5 I managed to update my `settings.gradle` to the following state:

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
//        gradleEnterprise()
        // other repositories...
    }
    resolutionStrategy {
        eachPlugin {
            if (requested.id.id == "com.gradle.enterprise") {
                useModule("com.gradle:enterprise-gradle-plugin:${requested.version}")
            }
        }
    }
    plugins {
        id("com.gradle.enterprise") version "3.6.3"
        // other plugins...
    }
//    repositories {
//        google()
//        mavenCentral()
//        gradlePluginPortal()
//    }
}
```

Is there a way to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the scoping of `pluginManagement {}` block. Make sure your `plugins {}` block is a top-level declaration as opposed to being inside of `pluginManagement {}`

Comment: I have eddited my code annd got this mistake 
Unexpected `plugins` block found. `plugins` can not appear before `pluginManagement`.
I have also tried moving `plugins {}` to `build.gradle` instead of `settings.gradle`. However thiis didn't help

Comment: Make sure you specify your plugins block in after pluginManagement. And to be able to configure settings plugins they have to be applied in settings.gradle(.kts) so moving a plugin like gradle enterprise into a build.gradle(.kts) won't work